# android Jackson @JsonIgnore property

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

In my API response, I have two fields: `event_date` and `event_datetime`. `event_date` returns **ISO date** format and In my android class, I have this variable as **String** type. I want to ignore this property in Jackson as it throws error of type mismatch. Note that I want to ignore this field only in response. I want to use this field as request parameter.

I have tried @JsonIgnore annotation but it is not working for me. Is there any other way to ignore this variable in Jackson?

```
@JsonIgnore
private String eventDate;
private String eventDateTime;

@JsonIgnore
public String getEventDate() {
    return eventDate;
}

@JsonProperty("event_date")
public void setEventDate(String eventDate) {
    this.eventDate = eventDate;
}

@JsonProperty("event_datetime")
public String getEventDateTime() {
    return eventDateTime;
}

public void setEventDateTime(String eventDateTime) {
    this.eventDateTime = eventDateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@JsonProperty("event_date")`. I think this is causing the problem.

Comment: I have to use this because my property name is **event_date** and not **eventDate**

Comment: But you want to ignore it. How comes that you are using it?

Comment: I wanted to ignore it only in response. I am using this field for request parameter. Anyway, i got the solution for that. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score -2):

That happens because you use the @JsonIgnore from org.fasterxml.jackson

Replace your import:

```
import org.fasterxml.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
```

to

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
```

Comment: I have used **com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.3** library. so i can not import the class u have specifed

Comment: org.codehaus.jackson will be in your project by default if you use jersey